# How to initiate push notification automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, wcf

I want to implement a push notification feature for an iPad app.
As per requirement Admin can decide when push notification should call.   Admin have a webpage where he can Add/Edit the time of the   initiation of PUSH notification.
How I implement this feature? 
We had hosted our website on our own Virtual Private server.
What is the  best method to achieve  the  above requirement?

1. Should I need to create a Windows service and monitor the push notification table in database  for initiate push  notification?
2. Should I need to create a WCF service   for push notification and call the service using  System scheduler?
3. Or any other best approach?

Please guide me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If notifications can appear at random times in the database then I would create Windows Service to poll the notifications table every X seconds/minutes (depends what you need).

WCF won't help you here, not sure how you wanted to use it. You can send APNS notifications [by using `PushSharp`](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) in the Windows Service.

However, if you want the database to be polled at larger intervals (in the hours) then create a console app (over PushSharp) and use Scheduled Tasks to run it periodically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check with Windows service.